# Is it possible to turn off aim assist in Halo 5? If so, how?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I had it multiple times now that I can't follow the same target when multiple targets are in my field of view due to aim assist (especially in warzone).  It will pull or resist against the way I want to take my reticle.  Is it possible to turn this aim assist off ?  If so how?  I couldn't find this under the in-game controller settings.

[I also think this is slowing my turning speed so I've had to bump my sensitivity up (past what I am comfortable with).]

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but no. This is one of those things that you hate when you notice it, but more often than not it really does assist you quiet well. One need only go into a custom game type and try and kill only people on your own team to notice how effective it is at making console shooters enjoyable.